# Missing class from Refactor -> Move in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I am trying to practice some refactoring design patterns and for this particular pattern I need to move one of my methods to a new class to handle complex conditionals.  Here is the class with the method I am trying to move

```
public class Grade
{
    public static double A_GRADE = 0.9;
    public static double B_GRADE = 0.8;
    public static double C_GRADE = 0.7;
    public static double D_GRADE = 0.6;

    private double grade;

    public Grade(double grade)
    {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    double getGrade() { return grade; }
    void setGrade (double newGrade) { this.grade = newGrade; }

    public String determineGradeLetter()
    {
        if (grade <= 1.0 && grade >= 0)
        {
            if (grade >= A_GRADE) { return "A"; }
            else if (grade >= B_GRADE) { return "B"; }
            else if (grade >= C_GRADE) { return "C"; }
            else if (grade >= D_GRADE) { return "D"; }
            else { return "F"; }
        }
        else { System.out.println("Invalid Grade") }
    }
}
```

I highlight the `determineGradeLetter()` method and do `Right Click -> Refactor -> Move`.  When the pop-up menu opens the class (called `GradeStrategy`) isn't listed.

What do you think might be going wrong?  I am running Eclipse Luna.

Also, I understand I can probably just copy and paste the method into the `GradeStrategy` class and add a `Grade` object in the `determineGradeLetter()` parameters, but I want to take full advantage of Eclipse's refactoring  capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your refactoring should still be compiling.  So eclipse needs to be able to determine possible targets to move the method to.

In your case there is no `GradeStrategy` available to which it can be moved.  Eclipse doesn't know what to do with the existing callers then.

If you had, for instance, a `GradeStrategy` as a parameter for your method, or as a field on `Grade`, then it could be moved since there were possible candidates.